# Union of queries with common ctes in sql achemy

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, common-table-expression

I have two queries with common ctes with same names in them when I tried to perform union on those two queries, it is giving me
"sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Multiple, unrelated CTEs found with the same name" error

I want to perform union of results from these two queries, please share if there is a way to handle this error. This is how I am trying to perform union operation

```
sa.union( history_stmt,
          future_stmt
        )
```

I want to achieve below query but when I tried to programmatically perform sa.union on two queries, it is giving me below error

> sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Multiple, unrelated CTEs found with the
> same name: 'seed'

Is there any way I can make the union query work without keeping different names.

```
    WITH seed AS (
SELECT
    *
FROM
    SEEDD_MATERIALIZED
WHERE
    LOCATION_ID = 7
    AND PRODUCT_ID = 29
),
history AS(
SELECT
    *
FROM
    history_table
)
SELECT
    PROFIT
FROM
    seed
LEFT OUTER JOIN history
ON
    seed.cluster_id = history.cluster_id
UNION   
WITH seed AS (
SELECT
    *
FROM
    SEED_MATERIALIZED
WHERE
    LOCATION_ID = 7
    AND PRODUCT_ID = 29
),
future AS(
SELECT
    *
FROM
    future_table
WHERE 
    strategy_id = 4
)
SELECT
    PROFIT
FROM
    seed
LEFT OUTER JOIN future
ON
    seed.cluster_id = future.cluster_id
```

Comment: Could you share the core?

Comment: @gotqn, updated my question with sample query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try first defining the CTEs and then refer them in the union classes:

```
WITH seed AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        SEED_MATERIALIZED
    WHERE
        LOCATION_ID = 7
        AND PRODUCT_ID = 29
),
history AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        history_table
),
future AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        future_table
    WHERE
        strategy_id = 4
)
SELECT
    PROFIT
FROM
    seed
LEFT OUTER JOIN history
ON
    seed.cluster_id = history.cluster_id
UNION
SELECT
    PROFIT
FROM
    seed
LEFT OUTER JOIN future
ON
    seed.cluster_id = future.cluster_id
```

Also, there is no need of the future and history CTE:

```
WITH seed AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        SEED_MATERIALIZED
    WHERE
        LOCATION_ID = 7
        AND PRODUCT_ID = 29
)
SELECT
    PROFIT
FROM
    seed
LEFT OUTER JOIN history_table
ON
    seed.cluster_id = history_table.cluster_id
UNION
SELECT
    PROFIT
FROM
    seed
LEFT OUTER JOIN future_table
ON
    seed.cluster_id = future_table.cluster_id
    AND future_table.strategy_id = 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you help me understand why sqlalchemy is giving compile time error while the same query in question runs fine in sql editor

Comment: @arkay it's some kind of syntax limitation I guess.